# Context-Based Hiding

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to develop a 'context-based hiding' feature on up and down mouse action for a project. I'm scratching my head how to develop it. I've seen website have that feature see:
http://www.teehanlax.com/story/social-portrait/

If you don't know what 'context-based hiding' is, see: http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/23/smart-transitions-in-user-experience-design/

Any there any snippets or advice of any sort js library that exist, please advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a number of ways.

- **[Example by codrops](http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/OnScrollEffectLayout/)**
- **[Gathering of 20 different plugins / examples](http://codegeekz.com/20-jquery-plugins-for-scrolling-effects/)**

Don't forget to really make your page shine by using AJAX to dynamically load and remove content from the page :)

Comment: you had embed the incorrect url. both links to take me to the same url.